# How to show custom image in map marker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I need to show custom image as location marker in my site.

Here i have attached image.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxAzy.jpg)

Comment: add some code there that you tried

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
//append jquery map marker js


<div id="googlemaps"></div>
```

script

```
    var mapMarkers =    {
                            "markers":
                            [
                                {
                                    "latitude": "48.85661",
                                    "longitude":"2.35222",
                                    "icon": "../wp-content/uploads/2016/08/pin.png"
                                }
                            ]
                        };
    $("#googlemaps").mapmarker
    ({
        zoom : 16,
        center : "48.85661, 2.35222",
        dragging : 1,
        mousewheel : 0,
        markers : mapMarkers,
        featureType : "all",
        visibility : "on",
        elementType : "geometry"
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback Suresh.

Comment: I have already implement this feature. but it's just showing image.

Comment: @RameshChudasama why you not combine two image in single image?

Comment: i think u should combine two image in single image then after set path javascript

Comment: How can i combine two images ?